# How to remove &nbsp; from hr in wordpress visual editor

Tags: visual-editor

Hi in wp visual editor whenever I add the `hr` from the inbuilt visual editor button it also adds `&nbsp;` which is kind a annoying as I have delete it every time manually. Does anyone know any way so that it doesnt add that `&nbsp;`?

P.S.:
Few days ago I've posted a wordpress bug which no one has looked into and post any reply. Here is the link - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-comment-bug-2?replies=1
So if any person from wordpress team is reading this post, please look into it.

Comment: Can anyone help?